# Laravel project is not opening in browser using Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I know this question may be overlapping but I have tried most of all answers in online that I could find. But no success so far. So, anyone please help me out.

I am new to both Homestead and Laravel. This is my configuration and details about installation below:

- Homestead 7 installed
- Vagrant 2.0.3 installed
- Composer 1.6.4 installed
- Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.2.8 installed
- git bash 2.16.1.windows.4 installed
- Windows 10 O/S is my Main base O/S
- On VirtualBox Manager I got these data=> Name: homestead-7, O/S: Ubuntu (64-bit), Base Memory: 2048 MB, Boot Order: Hard Disk, Optical, Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-V, Nested Paging, PAE/NX, KVM Paravirtualization..... so on
- In `c:/Laravel_P` folder I installed Laravel using Composer in Git Bash:

  ```
  cd /c/Laravel_P

  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel wetest
  ```

  After about command, i got 26.3 MB wetest folder in `Laravel_P` folder, which was successful installation of Laravel.
- Then I backdown from folders to my root by `cd` command and go to Homestead folder by `cd Homestead`. After I enter the Homestead folder, I run command:

  ```
  vagrant up
  ```

  This runs my Homestead Vagrant successfully (I checked in VB) and when processing this command no any error was shown.
- I change my homestead.yaml file to this as my system placements.

  ```
  authorize: C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

  keys:
      - C:/Users/my_user/.ssh/id_rsa
  folders:
      - map: C:/Laravel_P
        to: /home/vagrant/code

  sites:
      - map: homestead.wetest
        to: /home/vagrant/code/wetest/public
  ```
- Also changed my host file and saved the change:

  ```
  127.0.0.1       localhost

  ::1             localhost

  192.168.10.10   homestead.wetest
  ```
- Then i run another command:

  ```
  vagrant provision
  ```

  I have tried also `vagrant reload --provision` command also
- Now, when i tried to access my Laravel project from

  http://homestead.wetest

  I got Error:

> This site can’t be reached
>       homestead.wetest’s server IP address could not be found.

In my knowledge, I tried every step as found in web and documentation in Laravel, but why am I not getting the desired result? Please anyone help me in this.

Comment: is it available by 192.168.10.10 ?

Comment: @dyachenko  I'm sorry, what do you mean by available by 192.168.10.10. Do you mean is this ip is available in my system?

Comment: try to access your site from http://192.168.10.10 it should be available

Comment: Oh ! sorry, yeah it got access from 192.168.10.10. But not from link homestead.wetest which i already added in host file.

Comment: try to find which ip resolved your host. Run in windows console  `nslookup homestead.wetest`

Comment: @dyachenko  Sorry late replay. nslookup gives ERROR"Server:  UnKnown Address:  fe80::1*** UnKnown can't find homestead.wetest: Non-existent domain". I am trying couple of solution for this from what i got in web, no solution. Any way thank for your comments, it gives me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
folders:
- map: C:/Laravel_P
  to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
- map: homestead.wetest
  to: /home/vagrant/code/wetest/public
```

should be to: `/home/vagrant/code/public`